# storeUrl and password are not required .env issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, shopify, gatsby

I have an issue using gatsby-source-shopify , i have inside the .env file :

```
GATSBY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN = xxxxx
GATSBY_SHOPIFY_STORE_URL= xxxxxx.myshopify.com/
SHOPIFY_SHOP_PASSWORD= xxx
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config()
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteTitle: "xxxx",
    siteTitleDefault: "xxxx",
    siteUrl: "xxxxxxx.myshopify.com/",
    hrefLang: "en",
  },
  flags: {
    FAST_DEV: true,
  },


 plugins: [
   { resolve: "gatsby-source-shopify",
    options: {
      password: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD,
      storeUrl: process.env.GATSBY_MYSHOPIFY_URL,
      // salesChannel: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_ID, // Optional but recommended
    },
},
]
```

eventually when i run `gatsby  develop` i get this issue :

Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-shopify":

- "storeUrl" is required
- "password" is required

not finished load plugins - 0.807s
it's like .env is not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your variable names, the names in the .env and the names in the code don't actually match. You could update the code to:

```js
{ resolve: "gatsby-source-shopify",
    options: {
      password: process.env.SHOPIFY_SHOP_PASSWORD,
      storeUrl: process.env.GATSBY_SHOPIFY_STORE_URL,
      // salesChannel: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_ID, // Optional but recommended
    },
}
```